# Allowing user submitted JS to be executed without comprimising security

Tags: javascript, php, security

Apologies as this is rather vague, I know.

I'm developing a website where users can submit their own apps to be executed on the website. These apps will be executed in javascript and available for anyone on the site to run in their browser. The problem is I need to limit what aspects of javascript the users are able to access in their apps. All I want them to be able to do is:

- Create and manipulate their own variables and functions.
- Make calls to a predefined JS API written by myself.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm considering two options right now. Either they write it in JS and I make sure there's no nasty code in there or they write it in a language such as python and I iterate through this turning it into safe javascript.

All my server side stuff is in PHP so I'm looking to manipulate the user submitted code as a PHP string.

Again, I apologize, I'm not asking people to write code for me and I know this site is meant to be for specific code bugs but I don't know what else to do with this problem.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://developers.google.com/caja/

Comment: That's really, really helpful. Thank you! Although that seems to be more focused on general HTML with accompanying CSS/JS it does seem like I could use that for my standalone JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the method I used was [Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/) as this allowed my to implement code written in JavaScript into the page and confine it. It has several configurations but it worked best for me by totally refusing it DOM access and allowing it access to my own domain to grab images but no other network access (this was achieved with the URI policy).

Thanks very much to Blender for this recommendation, it was very helpful!

Comment: For future reference: After experimenting with this quite a lot I really struggled to get it to work. A lot of the 3rd party script was simply not running and I am really struggling to work out why.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I see is to create a sandboxed environment. Try [this](http://sns.cs.princeton.edu/2012/04/javascript-in-javascript-js-js-sandboxing-third-party-scripts/) (I never used it). If that doesn't work you should consider to define a metalanguage so that users submit the script in this metalanguage and them "compile" them to javascript. Any other option is dangerous because you are uploading scripts to your server.

Comment: The metalanguage is one option I have strongly considered as this would also allow me to provide a neater and easy to understand code for the front end users. Problem is I got a bit stuck on that idea and got lost whilst trying to write a "compiler" in php.

Comment: Does anyone have any recommendations on how exactly to process this metalanguage? A link or something would be helpful.

Comment: Php it's not the easiest programming language to implement a metalanguage.

In python you have many examples that can put you on the way. Take a look on shlex, for example: [shlex] (http://pymotw.com/2/shlex/). With a lexer you can treat string and separators easily so that you can transform the syntax that you define into javascript.

Take a look at

Comment: I went with caja in the end, worked out being by far the simplest option for me.

Comment: Thxs for the feedback. I'll see Caja too (it looks a good and mature project).